# Has Topalov retired?

Tags: famous-players

Topalov's rating hasn't changed since a long time. And he hasn't signed for any of the upcoming tournaments. I wonder if he has retired, after reaching that 2800 mark? He isn't playing the Grand Prix even.

Comment: Only Topalov can answer your question...

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff Of course. But he may have already answered it, e.g., in an interview.

Comment: Topalov just played an event a few months ago. Voted to close.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a "this-moment-in-time" question that is unlikely to be useful to future visitors.

Comment: I am sorry for asking a question not fit for the website. Should I delete the question? Please advise.

Comment: Although closed here is the answer: No. Because Topalov is playing here: http://www.gibraltarchesscongress.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there is no reason to suppose Veselin Topalov has retired.

> "Topalov's rating hasn't changed since a long time"

The last change in [Topalov's rating](http://ratings.fide.com/id.phtml?event=2900084) was in October, just two months ago. He has previously spent periods of up to 4 months without playing. So that seems normal.

> "I wonder if he has retired, after reaching that 2800 mark?"

Topalov has been above 2800 before. His maximum rating was 2813 in 2006 and again in 2009. I don't see any reason why he should stop.

> "He isn't playing the Grand Prix even."

According to [this interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aESw9LhsmzM) (minute 8:30) given during the Chess Olympiad, he isn't a great fan of the Grand Prix series (see also [here](https://chess24.com/en/read/news/caruana-tops-grand-prix-line-up)).